# How to POST to a controller in integration testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-6.0

I'm writing integration tests for an ASP.NET Core MVC app using WebApplicationFactory which provides a HttpClient to make calls against controllers.

I'm trying to test an update method on a controller. The update method in the controller takes a ViewModel as a parameter. When I call the HttpClient method PostAsync, the controller method is called but the ViewModel it receives doesn't contain the data I passed it. What am I doing wrong?

```
[Fact]
    public async Task UpdateTestAsync()
    {
        var newNotes = "These notes have now been changed";

        var dto = new TestVm
        {
            Action = "Update",
            Id = 2,
            CreatedBy = "Some guy",
            CreatedDate = new DateTime(2023, 08, 02, 14, 30, 05),
            Closed = false,
            Notes = newNotes
        };

        var client = mockWebApp.GetClient();
        var content = JsonContent.Create(dto);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("/Tests/Update", content);
        var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RecordResponse>(responseStr);

        var context = mockWebApp.Context?.Referral;
        var referral = context?.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == 2);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        res.ShouldNotBeNull();
        res.Error.ShouldBeFalse();

        referral.ShouldNotBeNull();
        referral.Notes.ShouldBe(newNotes);
    }
```

Here is the controller that is not receiving the viewmodel data submitted from the integration test method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(TestVm vm)
    {
        var dto = mapper.Map<TestDto>(vm);

        var res = await mediator.Send(new UpdateTestCommand { Dto = dto });

        if (res != null
            && !res.Error
            && dto.Action == FormSaveActions.SaveAndExit)
        {
            res.RedirectControllerRoute = "Tests";
            res.RedirectActionRoute = "Index";
        }

        return Json(res);
    }
```

Side note: When I call the controller method directly instead of using the HttpClient, it works fine:

```
var controller = new TestsController(
            mockWebApp.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(),
            mockWebApp.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>());

        var result = await controller.UpdateAsync(vm);
```

Comment: Few pointers:
- are you able to debug the controller during the test execution?
- is the action on the controller expecting the dto from the request body?

Comment: Hello to a fellow David. Yes and no. I've updated the answer with the controller code :)

Comment: hello fellow David :) so what is exactly happening? You're receiving a null dto ? And why you are not able to debug the controller? Just FYI, you could use the WebApplicationFactory class to run an instance of your API in memory during the tests, that would help debugging it (details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0 )

Comment: :) I can debug the controller, that's how I'm able to see that the TestVm just contains empty/null data in the controller method.

Comment: gotcha. Well then try using PostAsJsonAsync instead of PostAsync. And pass the dto directly instead of serializing it to JSON

Comment: Okay I just tried that. Same issue. No exception thrown.

Comment: that's weird. Try decorating the action parameter with the [FromBody] attribute ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute ). Also, just for curiosity, could you post the code for the TestVm class?

Comment: BTW, this is slightly unrelated, but I think there's a bit of confusion with the naming :)
DTOs are "Data Transfer Objects", basically they're the objects you send across the wire. "View Models" instead are the ones you normally use to represent data on screen, after you've loaded it from a DB and mapped. "Models" instead represent your actual Domain and are what the backend service uses for its logic

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I just forgot to rename some variable names after some previous changes. The application layer is returning dto's, I then map those to viewmodels before passing them to the view. For the update, the view returns the updated viewmodel by a form submit. I map the vm back to the dto and pass the dto back to the application layer :)

Comment: that should do :) Did the [FromBody] attribute work?

Comment: You absolute legend, adding the [FromBody] attribute worked! Much appreciations. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Athough, adding [FromBody] has not stopped the update method in the actual application from working ;(

Comment: because your app is probably POSTing it as form data. In that case you either update the app to properly send a JSON object in the body, or you add the [FromForm] attribute to the action (just to be more explicit) and update the test to send data as form content instead

Comment: Makes sense. I'll explore those options. Many appreciations mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here is that the controller action doesn't really know where to look for the incoming DTO.

Add either a [FromBody] or a [FromForm] attribute to the action's argument and update your tests accordingly.

I'd recommend mimicking as much as possible what your application does: if it is sending data as a result of a form submit, then use [FromForm].

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0